# java completion

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-java

I am always having problems, this time with java auto completion. I try to use the installation mentioned [here](https://github.com/bpowell/vim-android), so that I can use `vim` to do my android development. However, after the installation, on editing of java files, it has errors:

```
"MainActivity.java" 189L, 7779C
"project.properties" [New File]
Cannot open file "project.properties"
Error detected while processing function FindManifestFile:
line   44:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 35, in <module>
vim.error: Vim(vimgrep):E480: No match: target=
Error detected while processing function <SNR>6_LoadFTPlugin:
line   17:
E170: Missing :endfor
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

It seems like it is error of the plugin [`javacomplete`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785). How can I solve the problem? BTW, how can I locate error that `vim` is having on starting so that I can solve them by myself? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The error is from [vim-android](https://github.com/bpowell/vim-android/blob/master/findAndroidManifest/after/ftplugin/java.vim#L36). Your `project.properties` file don't have a line with `target=`.

There is a new version for the java plugin [vim-javacomplete2](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2).

Comment: But where should the `project.properties` file supposed to be?

Comment: On the main folder from your project http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/directorystructure-of-android-project.html#.Vs7wZHom1uY